# Android Emulators get freeze in Macbook pro M2 2022

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, android-emulator

I purchased a new Macbook pro M2 2022 and installed android studio Iguana 2024. Everything is good but when I installing emulator it run fine in start but after little time the freezes and stuck and not perform any other action until I kill it and restart it.

I already see few solution like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/74065/android-sdk-emulator-freezes-on-a-mac-running-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard#:%7E:text=The%20solution%20to%20the%20freezing,flag%20when%20starting%20the%20emulator.). I also reinstall emulator in Android SDK inside android studio settings but nothing solve my problem. Please anyone expert in solving this issue help me. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem on my `Macbook` `M1` Pro. Look like it's an Iguana version bug. So i would suggest to downgrade to Android Studio Hedgehog or use `VSCode` as temporary solution

[Android Studio download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive)

Comment: Yes you are right, I download "Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Canary 12" and this freezing issue not come again. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also got this bug on Windows 11, so Iguana Emulator is absolutely broken for now

Answer (score 0):

init emulator with adb commands and works perfect

steps:

1: open this command in terminal, example in mac

"cd /Users/MyUser/Library/Android/sdk/emulator"

```
Mac - /Users/<user>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
Linux - /home/<user>/Android/Sdk/emulator
Windows - C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
```

2: $ emulator -list-avds

Pixel_2_API_29

Pixel_3_API_28

Pixel_XL_API_24

Pixel_XL_API_25

example:

in mac "./emulator -list-avds"

3: $ emulator -avd <non_production_avd_name> -writable-system -no-snapshot

in mac

"./emulator -avd Pixel_XL_API_25 -writable-system -no-snapshot"

Comment: Hey E M thank you for your answer, can you please tell me command, as I am little new in this.

Comment: i'm update my answer with commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A new version of Android Emulator is available which fixes the mentioned issue.

Go to the Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools

And update the emulator to 34.1.19 This fixed the exact problem for me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. I actually moved to Android studio Preview. It not only good with emulators but also has Studio Bot and AI suggestion inside IDE that looks so cool.