# Android Emulator Freezing but unfreezing when resize window

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I updated Android Studio to latest (**Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1**) and emulator (**Android 13 | x86_64 31.3.10**), and now I experience **emulator screen freeze**.

After sometime running the emulator, it freezes when I hit the run "hot restart".
Although, when I resize the "Running Devices" window, I can see the emulator screen rendering. It stops when I stop resizing.

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Specs:
**OS**: Windows 10, version 10.0.19045, Build 19045;
**RAM**: 32BG

Comment: When I close emulator and "Invalidate Caches...", it unfreezes, but the problem will come again

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried updating HAXM and changing emulator graphics settings, these resolve the issue but it will occur again after hot restart.

Comment: I'm having the same issue since I updated to Iguana. The way I reproduce it on my side most of the time is by resizing the "Running devices". Then it seems that the emulator doesn't respond to touch so I have to resize the frame to make it refresh. After closing and relaunching emulator it is OK until it happens again. Notes: I using a Macbook and the "View Mode" for the emulator is set to "Dock Pinned" on Android Studio

Comment: same issue for me, rotating the device in the emulator seems to unfreeze it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A new version of Android Emulator is available which fixes the mentioned issue.

Go to the Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools

And update the emulator to 34.1.19
This fixed the exact problem for me.

Comment: I recently updated emulator to that version too it's working fine now. Was thinking of waiting for a full week to monitor if the bug comes back...but it's probably fixed by now.

Comment: Same thing on Mac OS (Sonoma, 13.3, 13.4). This is the fix!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, this happened to me as a result of updating to the latest Iguana version, I thought that going back to the previous version would solve it but that is not the case, I still have the same problem since then, if someone finds a definitive solution it would be a great help .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I already answered this question here: [Android Emulators get freeze in Macbook pro M2 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78105857/android-emulators-get-freeze-in-macbook-pro-m2-2022/78109062#78109062)

It's Android Studio Iguana verison bug. So just downgrade to Android Studio Hedgehog or use VScode as temporary solution.

Comment: First, I'm using Windows 10, second, for me the bug started at Android Studio Hedgehog. But I will consider using VSCode

Comment: Why would using another IDE solve the emulator issue? The emulator can be run as a standalone application which seems like a much better solution than changing IDE
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline